# Run TestCafe in Firefox browser using docker container via Jenkins

Tags: firefox, jenkins, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to run the TestCafe in firefox browser(not headless) through Jenkins.
I'm using docker container which has chromium and firefox installed.

When I try to run it firefox it's throwing an error as

```
ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.
```

My Jenkins file looks like

```
steps
        {
            container('testcafe') {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh "npm run live-docker"
            }
        }
```

where `live-docker` is mentioned in `package.json` as `"live-docker":"testcafe 'firefox --no-sandbox' e2e/user.spec.js -r xunit:TEST-new_user.xml”`

I even tried using `"live-docker":"testcafe firefox e2e/user.spec.js -r xunit:TEST-new_user.xml”` but getting the same error.

Comment: Do you start Xvfb and a window manager (e,g, Fluxbox) in your container before starting TestCafe? They are required to run browsers in the regular (not headless) mode in containers. Check how it is done in the official TestCafe docker image - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/docker. 

You also can try to use the official TestCafe image and check if the problem can be reproduced with it and share your image or Dockerfile. This will help a lot.